# Why MongoDB Profiling output give me high Millis but small executionTimeMillisEstimate

Tags: mongodb, performance, profiler, execution-time

MongoDB profiling output provide me:

```
 "op" : "query",
  "ntoskip" : 0,
  "nscanned" : 1,
  "nscannedObjects" : 1,
  "keyUpdates" : 0,
  "writeConflicts" : 0,
  "numYield" : 0,
  ..
  "nreturned" : 1,
  "responseLength" : 148,
  "millis" : 1488,
  "execStats" : {
    "stage" : "LIMIT",
    "nReturned" : 1,
    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
     ...
    "inputStage" : {
      "stage" : "FETCH",
      "nReturned" : 1,
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
      ...
      "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
        "nReturned" : 1,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
       ..
        "keysExamined" : 1,
        "dupsTested" : 0,
        "dupsDropped" : 0,
        "seenInvalidated" : 0,
        "matchTested" : 0
      }
    ...
```

I am wondering why it indicate 1488 millis for the whole operation, but we have 0 as each executionTimeMillisEstimate on each STAGE.  Also, I have

```
"nscanned" : 1,  
"nscannedObjects" : 1 
"numYield" : 0
```